# How to pick a Number that changes in a list python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list with product orders and I need to pick the number from the order `order_id:TheNumberIwant`. I have tried some stuff but none do the trick. I can't Access the number because can change the location in the list, but always comes after the `order_id:`. I have tried using the split method but only pick one of the `order_id`and I need to pick all of then.

here is what I'm doing:

i have this string

> {"data":[{"order_id":744152,"pedido_venda":"Z921211","supplier_id":11042,.....

```
    with  open("items.txt","r") as file:
        data = file.readlines()            
for line in data:
    word = line.split("order_id:" )
    abre_arquivo1 = open("items2.txt","w")
    abre_arquivo1.write("%s\n" % word)
    abre_arquivo1.close()
```

This removes the `order_id` but i want the number that comes after in the string to save in the "items2.txt".

Comment: Can you provide some more details (e.g. example code) because it is hard to figure out how to help you otherwise...

Comment: I have updated the question with more info.

Comment: sample output ?

Comment: It looks like JSON. If it is, you can use the function `loads` in the `json` module to read the data into a variable, for example `d`, and then access the order_id in the python way: `d['data'][0]['order_id']` (and for 1, 2 etc.)

Comment: I have updated the question with more info.I'm using json now,much easier this way. Thanks for the help.